# Break a binary string down to segments

Tags: python, regex, string

The task here is to break down a string `110011110110000` into a list:

```
['11', '00', '1111', '0', '11', '0000']
```

My solution is

```
str1='110011110110000'
seg = []
a0=str1[0]
seg0=''
for a in str1:
    print('a=',a)
    if a==a0:
        seg0=seg0+a
    else:
        print('seg0=',seg0)
        seg.append(seg0)
        seg0=a
        a0=a
seg.append(seg0)
seg
```

It's ugly and I am sure you guys out there have a one-liner for this. Maybe regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
str1='110011110110000'

from itertools import groupby

l = [v * len([*g]) for v, g in groupby(str1)]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['11', '00', '1111', '0', '11', '0000']
```

EDIT: version with regex:

```
str1='110011110110000'
import re
print([g[0] for g in re.findall(r'((\d)\2*)', str1)])
```

Comment: I knew it! That's the one-liner I am looking for. Thanks @Andrej-Kesely

Answer (score 3):

Here is a regex solution:

```
result = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r'(([10])\2*)', str1)]
```

The regex is `(([10])\2*)`, find a 0 or 1, then keep looking for that same thing. Since `findall` returns all groups in the match, we need to map it to the first group (Group 2 is the `([10])` bit).

Comment: Actually, this answer has a flaw: it returns: ['11', '00', '1111', '11', '0000'].

Comment: @uqji Oops! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative regex approach, using the simple pattern `1+|0+`:

```
str1 = "110011110110000"
pattern = re.compile(r'(1+|0+)')
result = []

for m in re.finditer(pattern, str1):
    result.append(m.group(0))

print(result)
```

This prints:

```
['11', '00', '1111', '0', '11', '0000']
```

Note that we might want to instead use `re.split` here.  The problem with `re.split` is that it doesn't seem to support splitting on lookarounds.  In other languages, such as Java, we could try splitting on this pattern:

```
(?<=0)(?=1)|(?<=1)(?=0)
```

This would nicely generate the array/list we expect.

Answer (score 1):

one line solution using `groupy`

```
from itertools import groupby     

text='1100111101100001'    
sol = [''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(text)]

print(sol)
```

output

```
['11', '00', '1111', '0', '11', '0000', '1']
```

not regex solution, but improvement on ur code

```
str1='110011110110000'

def func(string):
    tmp = string[0]
    res =[]
    for i, v in enumerate(string, 1):
        if v==tmp[-1]:
            tmp+=v
        else:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp=v
    res.append(tmp)
    return res

print(func(str1))
```

output

```
['111', '00', '1111', '0', '11', '0000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use general regex `(.)\1*`

`(.)` - match single character (any) and store it in first capturing group

`\1*` - repeat what's ca[ptured in first captruing group zero or more times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMgQ4w/1)

Matches collection will be your desired result.